# Implementing push notification service with Mongo and Apache camel

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement APNS notification service using apache camel and mongo for queueing and I am stuck in a very beginning. My apnsProcessor is not called.
This is my route

```
from("mongodb:mongo?database=apns&collection=notification_push_queue")
        .to("bean:apnsProcessor");
```

These are the logs

```
Initialising MongoDb endpoint: Endpoint[mongodb://mongo?collection=notification_push_queue&database=apns]
Starting MongoDB Tailable Cursor consumer, binding to collection: db: apns, col: notification_push_queue
Stopping MongoDB Tailable Cursor consumer, bound to collection: db: apns, col: notification_push_queue
```

What am I doing wrong? Why camel does not pass messages to my bean?